# Uncaught ReferenceError: amadeus is not defined at REPL16:1:39 while saving data using mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Encountered an error while trying to save data in mongoDB using mongoose.

index.js file -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp')
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Connection established!")
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Error!")
        console.log(e)
    })
    
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    year: Number,
    score: Number,
    rating: String
})

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema)
const amadeus = new Movie({ title: 'Amadeus', year: 1984, score: 8.4, rating: 'PG'})
```

I loaded this file from node terminal using - `.load index.js`
and then tried to save amadeus using - `amadeus.save()` but it gave this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: amadeus is not defined
> at REPL16:1:39

But the 'myapp' db and 'movies' collection was created and I'm able to access it from mongo shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to the above problem is to run the index.js file using - `node -i -e "$(< index.js)"` inside the system terminal and not inside the node shell.
The reason of this error is maybe related to the new version of Node.js